# Haskell - Sum up probability list

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm going through Learn You A Haskell and just finished the part "For a few monads more". In this part we created a `newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a, Rational)] }` and created a `Monad` instance for it. This allows us to calculate probabilities of results in non-deterministic calculations like the following:

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails deriving (Show, Eq)

coin :: Prob Coin
coin = Prob [(Heads, 1%2), (Tails, 1%2)]

loadedCoin :: Prob Coin
loadedCoin = Prob [(Heads, 1%10), (Tails, 9%10)]

coinTest :: Prob Bool
coinTest = do
    a <- coin
    b <- coin
    c <- loadedCoin
    return (all (==Tails) [a,b,c])
```

Of course, this doesn't generate a very pretty result:

```
getProb coinTest
>> [(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]
```

It was left as an exercise to the reader to write a neat function to sum up all the `False`s and all the `True`s so we get `[(True,9 % 40),(False,31 % 40)]`. I've managed to do this, sort of. It works for this particular case, but I feel like it isn't a useful function at all since it's so specialized. Here's what I came up with:

```
sumProbs :: Prob Bool -> Prob Bool
sumProbs (Prob ps) = let (trues, falses) = partition fst ps
                         ptrue = reduce trues
                         pfalse = reduce falses
                     in Prob [ptrue, pfalse]
                     where reduce = foldr1 (\(b,r) (_,r') -> (b,r+r'))
```

I'd love to generalize it to work for any `Eq a => Prob a`, but so far no luck. I was thinking of maybe using a `Map` together with `unionWith` or something like that. Or maybe I can exploit the fact that `(a,b)` has a `Functor b` instance? I think I'm missing some simpler more elegant solution.

So, to sum it up: How can I write a function `sumProbs :: (Eq a) => Prob a -> Prob a` that sums up all the probabilities that share the same value (key)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Data.Map`, then [`fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:fromListWith) and [`toList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:toList) will do:

```
import Data.Map (toList, fromListWith)

newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a, Rational)] }
    deriving Show

sumProbs :: (Ord a) => Prob a -> Prob a
sumProbs = Prob . toList . fromListWith (+) . getProb
```

---

Relaxing `Ord a` to `Eq a` would require a less efficient quadratic computation; something like:

```
sumProbs :: (Eq a) => Prob a -> Prob a
sumProbs = Prob . foldr go [] . getProb
    where
    go (x, y) = run
        where
        run [] = (x, y):[]
        run ((a, b):rest)
            | x == a    = (x, y + b): rest
            | otherwise = (a, b): run rest
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is very clean. I guess the downside is that this requires and `Ord` constraint on a, whereas the other solution works with `Eq` (I think the `sortBy` is unnecessary).

Comment: @Kai `groupBy` will _not_ group if the keys of equal value are not next to each other (try `group [1, 2, 1]`). so the `sortBy` is necessary

Comment: Oh, well that settles it then! I suppose this is for performance reasons?

Comment: @kai  it _may_ perform faster if there are many duplicate keys (this will perform `n log u` where `u` is the number unique keys)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map` is a good idea, but you'll need `Ord a` in addition to `Eq a`. If you're ok with that, then we can also do simpler list solution: just replace `partition` with a combination of [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) and [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:groupBy):

```
import Data.List (groupBy, sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

sumProbs :: (Ord a) => Prob a -> Prob a
sumProbs (Prob ps) = Prob . map reduce
                   . groupBy ((==)`on`fst)
                   $ sortBy (compare`on`fst) ps
```

Comment: Oh my, that is handy! I was not familiar with `groupBy`/`orderBy` (although I've used them in other languages of course). Reading the code it's pretty obvious what it does, although I'm gonna have to read up on `on` and exercise my type-fu!

Comment: I don't suppose you know a way to get rid of the rather ugly lambda in `foldr1 (\(b,r) (_,r') -> (b,r+r'))`?

Comment: @kai: IMO that lambda is just fine, but you can do `foldr1 (second . (+) . snd)` if you prefer.